# Missing id from XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

I don't understand why my code can't find R.id.saveItem while it is in xml file. Any suggestions why this can happen?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    case android.R.id.saveItem: // error - can't find saveItem
        // do something
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Part of XML file (detail_menu.xml):

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/saveItem"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/save">
</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `case android.R.id.saveItem`. Instead try `case R.id.saveItem:`

Comment: this. Android.R is completely different from R

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use android.R.

Replace 'android.R.id.saveItem' with simply 'R.id.saveItem', if eclipse (or whatever IDE you're using) cannot resolve R, import the one from your own package structure, not android.R